# Transaction is stuck, how to unstuck it?

Tags: transactions, metamask

I'm using metamask to send a transaction. It sent a transaction with nonce 3, and it has high gas price. However, it's not getting mined at all, now waiting for a long time? Why is it not mined?

I sent previously two more transactions. Metamas set a nonce of 1 and 2 for those. Those transaction are now cancelled. I created a new transaction with high gas price, but it's stuck again. What is happening?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7f707f5fee721866f05778b0308fcdd53654a58e07c6509ea7d40d48773fc5f0

Answer (score 2):

The transaction you linked has been replaced by transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x37302b3a3930b01ca940ffce9beb69bdaad6728204b46518a9b75cf2ff8eab3b . The old transaction had a gas price of 19 gWei while the new transaction had 28. As a miner can choose which transactions to include they had picked the one with the higher gas price. Once a transaction gets mined the other transactions with the same nonce are no longer valid and are dropped.

So you have basically replaced the transaction with 19 gWei gas price with a newer transaction with 28 gWei.

If you have a look at https://ethgasstation.info/ you can see that 19 gWei is very low currently and wouldn't get mined for quite some time.